# Progress 4gl Secure Socket Authentication

Tags: sockets, authentication, progress-4gl, openedge

Currently attempting to perform a socket connection to a host that has authentication setup using the username:password@domain syntax. The following curl request works fine when run via command line:

```
/opt/pware/bin/curl -s -v -S -k -X POST -d @/test/worldpay.xml https://username:password@secure-test.worldpay.com/jsp/merchant/xml/paymentService.jsp
```

The problem lies when attempting to post the same worldpay.xml payload file using progress secure socket. My socket connects using the following:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE vhSocket AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
CREATE SOCKET vhSocket.

vhSocket:CONNECT('-H test.worldpay.com -S 443 -ssl -nohostverify') NO-ERROR.
IF vhSocket:CONNECTED() EQ FALSE THEN
DO: 
    Message "COULD NOT CONNECT".
    vhSocket:DISCONNECT().
    DELETE OBJECT vhSocket NO-ERROR.
    RETURN.
END.
ELSE
   Message "CONNECTED!".
```

I am setting up my header as follows once the socket connection is opened:

```
ASSIGN 
vRequest = 'POST ' +
username + ":" + password + "@" + "/jsp/merchant/xml/paymentService.jsp" +
' HTTPS/1.1' + chr(13) + chr(10) +
'Connect: close' + chr(13) + chr(10) +
'Host: ' + "secure-test.worldpay.com" + chr(13) + chr(10) +
'Content-Length: ' + string(LENGTH(postdata,"raw")) + chr(13) + chr(10) +
'Content-Type: text/xml' + chr(13) + chr(10) +
chr(13) + chr(10) +
postData +
chr(13) + chr(10).


set-byte-order(vData) = BIG-ENDIAN.
set-size(vData) = LENGTH(vRequest,"raw").
put-string(vData,1,LENGTH(vRequest,"raw")) = vRequest.

vReturnCode = vhSocket:WRITE(vData, 1, LENGTH(vRequest,"raw")).
```

Any help on figuring out how the header should be structured or how to perform basic authentication over Secure Sockets in Progress would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For http(s) basic authentication, you don't POST the username as part of the URL.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side

This is what we use in our http client, you'll have to change the call to AddHttpHeader to code that send that header line to the server socket.

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Purpose: Adds a basic authorization header to the request
    Notes:   
    @param pcUserName The UserName to use for basic authorization
    @param pcPassword The password to use for basic authorization
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
METHOD PUBLIC VOID SetBasicAuthorization (pcUserName AS CHARACTER,
                                          pcPassword AS CHARACTER):

    DEFINE VARIABLE cBase64        AS LONGCHAR NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE mAuthorization AS MEMPTR   NO-UNDO .

    ASSIGN cBase64 = SUBSTITUTE ("&1:&2":U, pcUserName, pcPassword) .

    SET-SIZE (mAuthorization) = LENGTH (cBase64) .

    PUT-STRING (mAuthorization, 1, LENGTH (cBase64)) = cBase64 .

    ASSIGN cBase64 = BASE64-ENCODE (mAuthorization) .

    AddHttpHeader (SUBSTITUTE ("Authorization Basic &1":U, cBase64)) .

    FINALLY:
        SET-SIZE (mAuthorization) = 0 .         
    END FINALLY.

END METHOD .
```

So in your case, try this:

```
ASSIGN 
vRequest = 'POST ' + "/jsp/merchant/xml/paymentService.jsp" +
' HTTPS/1.1' + chr(13) + chr(10) +
'Connect: close' + chr(13) + chr(10) +
'Host: ' + "secure-test.worldpay.com" + chr(13) + chr(10) +
'Content-Length: ' + string(LENGTH(postdata,"raw")) + chr(13) + chr(10) +
'Content-Type: text/xml' + chr(13) + chr(10) +
'Authorization: Basic ' + cBase64 + chr(13) + chr(10) +
chr(13) + chr(10) +
postData +
chr(13) + chr(10).
```

Comment: Your suggestion appears to have corrected the transmit issue. Thanks again Mike you're the man!